# PHP special characters replace function

Tags: php, function, replace, str-replace

When I replace é it changes into an Ã©. I am using UTF-8 encoding in PHP and HTML. I want the function to return the HTML code for the character I put into the function.

```
function ctrlspecialchars($subject){    
$search = array("<",">","é","à","â","ä","æ","ç","è","ê","ë","ï","î","ò","ó","ô","ö","ø","ù","ú","û","ü","©","®","«","»","¼","½","¾","±","§","¥","£","{","}","$","%");
$replace = array("&lt;","&gt;","&#233;","&#224;","&#226;","&#228;","&#230;","&#231;","&#232;","&#234;","&#235;","&#239;","&#238;","&#242;","&#243;","&#244;","&#246;","&#248;","&#249;","&#250;","&#251;","&#252;","&#169;","&#174;","&#171;","&#187;","&#188;","&#189;","&#190;","&#177;","&#167;","&#165;","&#163;","&#123;","&#125;","&#36;","&#37;");

return str_replace($search,$replace,$subject); 
 }
```

Comment: Does it show a question mark icon?

Comment: Ã©  -> these signs.  I've send the character é with a form, without the replace function it's gives me the right character... é but I want to replace tha

Comment: ... but I want to replace that character with the -> & # 233;
It's yet not even saved in the database !

Comment: Are you print it in the console or in the browser? I'm asking it, because I test your function in my local environment and it worked fine

Comment: @James  It's printed in the page. It's encoded with utf-8.
Without encoding with the replace function it shows itself as é à â ä æ ç è ê ë ï î ò ó ô ö ø ù ú û ü in the page, **WITH** encoding utf8_encode() or in the header it is shown as Ã© Ã Ã¢ Ã¤ Ã¦ Ã§ Ã¨ Ãª Ã« Ã¯ Ã® Ã² Ã³ Ã´ Ã¶ Ã¸ Ã in the page. 
I'm not even talking now about the database which is configured as utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci which should be better than the normpal utf-8 encoding, also in the DB it shows those weird characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try charset: iso-8859-1 instead of UTF-8 or be sure to set the charset in your html header:

```
PHP : header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
HTML: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: HTML 5 uses <meta charset="UTF-8">  but d I've also used  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">, and also header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); and also utf8_encode(...).
I've searched for hours and search the internet for solutions, see what others said about this problem. Nothing works.

Comment: Even <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-8"> gives me   �©  after the replace function

Comment: Are you sure that the input into the function is correct also? Maybe change the function parameter in one of the characters and see if it works.

Comment: I use the function this way : $varsubject=ctrlspecialchars($varsubject);
Nothing wrong, I deleted many characters to only three and I get the same result.

Comment: I tried again with only the 9 first characters and it gives me no sign anymore.   When I look in the sourcecode of the HTML page, I don't see characters like & # 233; but the normal é à etc. Is this normal ?

Comment: make $subject into '<', tell me what comes out.

Comment: The solution has nothing to do with the charset !  Even with utf-8 or ISO-8859-8  those weird signs kept showing themselves.  It seem that certain symbols are to blame. I don't understand why  :  ©  ®  «  » ¼  ½ ¾  ±   §   ¥   £  {  }  $  % .  Thanks, you suggested about those symbols...
But unfortunately in the database it says Ã© Ã  Ã¢ Ã¤ Ã¦ Ã§ Ã¨ Ãª Ã« Ã¯ Ã® Ã² Ã³ Ã´ Ã¶ Ã¸ Ã¹...  in stead of these kind & # 233;   So my replace function doesn't work at all.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''>'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\website\cms\form.php on line 13

Comment: Without encoding with the replace function it shows itself as é à â ä æ ç è ê ë ï î ò ó ô ö ø ù ú û ü  in the page, **WITH** encoding  utf8_encode() it is shown as  Ã© Ã Ã¢ Ã¤ Ã¦ Ã§ Ã¨ Ãª Ã« Ã¯ Ã® Ã² Ã³ Ã´ Ã¶ Ã¸ Ã in the page. I'm not even talking now about the database which is configured as utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci  which should be better than the normpal utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Since I copied your code and it works fine in my local environment, your problem shouldn't be in the code and should be indeed the encoding.

I don't know your encoding needs (maybe you need to print some special characters in some page), but for test purposes, try to keep all parts of your system to use UTF-8.
Follow the tips of @user2879055's answer, configure your Database to use `utf8_general_ci` and ensure that your PHP file is encoded in the UTF-8.

See below a image of my editor (I'm using Atom) configured to encoding the files in UTF-8. Most editors have a similar type of configuration. If your editor has two options of UTF-8 (with and without BOM), choose without BOM (informations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)).

[image: atom configuration]

Finally, if your are using Apache, add the line `IndexOptions +Charset=UTF-8` to your `.htacces`.

Avoid the use of `utf8_enconding` and `utf8_decode` functions during these tests.

When it works, change back the enconding configuration for each step and make a test, so you'll find where is the problem when your code fails again. Now you can configure your enviroment with your enconding needs and work just on the problematic part.

Just FIY, I'm using your function with `var_dump(ctrlspecialchars("<ó äî ò æ ç % ®>"));` and my browser is showing `/var/www/html/replace.php:10:string '&lt;&#243; &#228;&#238; &#242; &#230; &#231; &#37; &#174;&gt;' (length=61)`.

Comment: Even without a database I get those weird signs , thus when it's only printed in the page as a test !  The problem isn't the database (yet) but the page encoding. I'm still on localhost on my pc. I'm gonna try that .htaccess first.

Comment: Db is converted to utf8_general_ci and the php page and also in the .htaccess.  Same weird signs.   
I need those special characters because I live in Europe and we use ë ç à é è  some in french some in dutch.

Comment: This is really strange...Did you already try the [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlentities.php) like `print_r(htmlentities(ctrlspecialchars("<ó äî ò æ ç % ®>")));` or something similar?

Comment: In the Db I got now thanks to htmlentities  &ucirc; &icirc; &iuml; &ouml; &euml; &ugrave; &oacute; &eacute; &ccedil; &agrave; &egrave; 
Thus it's ignoring completely my function !  Yes very strange indeed.
Are these signs from html entities recognized by all browsers ?

Comment: Yes, it should work in any browser. see a list of html entities in this [site](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

Comment: Thanks, that function of mine was from before html5. I stopped programming but needed to do something again with a website. So HTML5 has now the entire list, what a luck for me.

Comment: I thought you need to do some processes with these html entities, but just for a visual purpose in a common modern browser, HTML5 and the `htmlentities()` solves your problem. Nice! :)